# Error in using RoleEnvironment to get Configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, azure

my web app is using MVC3 with razor

If I am trying to read anything from ServiceConfig using RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("senderName")
I am getting error related to Microsoft.IdentityModel

```
Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[SerializationException: Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +4727747
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +1725
   System.AppDomain.get_Id() +0
   <CrtImplementationDetails>.DoCallBackInDefaultDomain(IntPtr function, Void* cookie) +185
   <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport._Initialize(LanguageSupport* ) +328
   <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport* ) +102

[ModuleLoadException: The C++ module failed to load while attempting to initialize the default appdomain.
]
```

.

It's true that I am making use of Windows identity foundation for Azure  acs  authentication .But everything worked fine when I deployed to azure.But if I make use of RoleEnvironment to read any settings from my ServiceConfig  files (for ex :RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("Smtpserver")) .Its failing on azure .

But everything workes  fine on my local azure appfabric .If I am removing this line of code ,then all workes fine .`RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("Smtpserver"))`
I am using two webroles in my cloud app.
Please help me identify the cause of error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you installed the WIF on the Azure?

The most reliable way is to have the WIF runtime installed via a startup task. You check out [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206022/installing-a-wif-runtime-for-hosting-a-net-application-in-windows-azure). And I think [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495531/azure-sdk-1-4-wif-the-c-module-failed-to-load-while-attempting-to-initiali) is exact duplicate.

Comment: I am finding this error only if I try to read settings from ServiceConfig. Otherwise everything works perfectly fine.

Comment: did you thoroughly check both the referenced questions and their answers ?

Comment: If I am remotting to my azure webrole I can see WIF installed.

Comment: check the comments on my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206022/installing-a-wif-runtime-for-hosting-a-net-application-in-windows-azure - if you have VS Ultimate, try hunting down the issue with Intellitrace.